# Programming 328PB from Arduino IDE using Atmel-ICE to ICSP port

Tags: atmega328, isp

Updated question.  The original question was based on using 'Upload' from the Arduino IDE, instead of 'Upload Using Programmer' under 'Sketch'.  The problem in getting the Atmel-ICE to work with Arduino IDE appears now to be one of incorrect ICE drivers loaded when I installed Atmel Studio. [image: Device Manager conflict]

Arduino requires libusb-win drivers, which can be checked with Zadig.   Available here: https://zadig.akeo.ie/

This problem was 99% solved (with help) by selecting [image: Install WCID driver] and the libusb-win32 driver using Zadig.   I say 99% solved, because *my program now loads and runs!* , but I do get the red 'X' there as the WCID status.

Apologies if this amendment to the original question is not in the correct context, this is new to me.   Thank You.
Jaco

Comment: i think rhat the yellow exclamation mark in the device manager is an indication that windows cannot talk to the device ... try finding the correct drivers ... your post is unrelated to the arduino, so it is off topic here

Comment: Are you choosing "Upload" or "Upload **using programmer**"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure AVRDude needs that the Atmel-ICE has libusb drivers loaded to be able to interface with it (like in https://cyansensors.wordpress.com/portfolio/setting-up-atmel-ice-with-platformio-using-atmega328p/). What happens when you use https://zadig.akeo.ie/ to load libusb-win32 drivers? Also, the upload should happen via a USB device and not a COM port, so make sure to choose "Upload using programmer" when uploading. If that does not help, go to File -> Settings and enable "Verbose Upload" and post the log.

Comment: I think Maximilian you have put me on the right path.  Device Manager is happy with   the ICE now appearing under libusb-win32 devices.     I had indeed posted the error from 'Upload', which was in haste, as I had been using Upload Using Programmer.   Now the error is:   "avrdude: usbdev_send(): wrote -22 out of 7 bytes, err = 
avrdude: jtag3_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: failed to sync with the JTAGICE3 in ISP mode"    So it appears the Arduino IDE uses the JTAG mode, not the ICSP protocol?    An Auduino IDE configuration option?   Thank You.

Comment: I guess I was too subtle about this before, so I'm going to mention it one last time before disappearing: The things you did to *solve* the problem go in an *answer* and **not the question.**  Someone who discovers this later should be able to see a question (that they can understand, at least if they have the same problem) and *separate* from that an answer.

Comment: Apologies Timeage, I thought the answers were other users responses.   Will make corrections today.   Need here to get a fetter feel for how it's supposed to work.  Again, apologies, I mistakenly _thought_ I understood.

Comment: For reference, you said that it works 99% fine except that it won't load WCID driver (which I don't think is very ciritical?), but how did you resolve the error `avrdude: usbdev_send(): wrote -22 out of 7 bytes, err = avrdude: jtag3_send(): `?

Answer (score 1):

Hello The 328 "PB" has major issues with running external clocks...(yes I have first hand experience with this PB model)... Try switching to the internal oscillator as I can testify first hand the the external clocks on the PB don't work correctly. They tend to sell the PB a few bucks cheaper because you will only buy them once and only once when you find out how bad the external crystal clock driver is. If you look at the latest datasheet for the PB they try and talk their way out of the bad driver by explaining how you need to match capacitors with the following snippet. I call BS as the 328p never needed such precision on it Xtal1 & 2 pins to run but to be fair they PB is meant to be low power.

This Crystal Oscillator is a low power oscillator, with reduced voltage swing on the XTAL2 output. It gives
the lowest power consumption, but is not capable of driving other clock inputs, and may be **more
susceptible to noise in noisy environments.**
The crystal should be connected as described in Clock Source Connections. When selecting crystals,
load capacitance must be taken into consideration. The capacitance (Ce+Ci) needed at each TOSC pin
can be calculated by using:
�� + �� = 2�� − ��
where:
• Ce - is optional external capacitors. (= C1, C2 as shown in Figure 11-2)
• Ci - is the pin capacitance in Table 11-3.
• CL - is the load capacitance specified by the crystal vendor.
• CS - is the total stray capacitance for one XTAL pin.
Table 11-